# List storing other lists keeping its old index values after doubling main list size?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm having issues with attempting to double the size of a list that contains lists like so:

```
main_list = [[], [], [], []]
```

Say I want to add the word "test" at main_list[1]. That can be done simply by just:

```
main_list[1].append("test")
```

However, when I want to double the size of the main_list and therefor double the amount of lists I'm currently doing this:

```
        for a in main_list:
            while len(a) != 0:
                del a[0]
            if len(a) == 0:
                continue
```

This is to remove the old main_lists contents because I do not want the old lists contents to carry over to the doubled list.

Followed by:

```
main_list = main_list * 2
```

Here is where I run into issues. If I try to append test at index = 0 I would expect the outcome to be:

```
main_list[0].append("test")
print(main_list) --> [["test], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

However, the output that I get is instead:

```
main_list[0].append("test")
print(main_list) --> [["test], [], [], [], ["test], [], [], []]
```

So the old index values have obviously carried over to the new list. Is there an easy way to fix this? I was thinking about maybe doing a for-loop which forcefully changes the indexes to be correct, but it seems like that would be infeasible after the list has doubled a couple of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a new list of lists for `main_list`. When you do that, all the old lists will be lost:

```py
size = len(main_list) * 2
main_list = [[] for _ in range(size)]
main_list[0].append("test")
print(main_list)
```

Output as expected